# react redux middleware cannot access variable defined in utils

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-middleware

Hi I created a redux custom middleware and trying to call `apiUrl` contstant value defined and exported from ./utils/api.js file. but getting this error

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'apiUrl' before initialization

1. `.utils/api.js` file

```
    export const apiUrl = window.apiUrl || `${window.location.origin}/api`;
```

2. `redux-custom-middleware.js` file

```
    import * as api from './config/api';
    const apiUrl = api.apiUrl;
```

Though, this constant value is accessible in the entire app (all components and actions) but unable to access it inside redux custom middleware.

Thanks

Comment: Which of the two files does the error actually stem from?

Comment: I can access api.apiUrl variable throughout the app not in redux custom middleware file
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#writing-an-async-function-middleware

Comment: Ah, is your `redux-custom-middleware.js` (indirectly) imported by `./config/api`? The circular dependency could explain that error. The module isn't loaded yet, but another module is already trying to read its value.

Comment: No I am importing this custom middleware in configureStore.js. just like we add thunk middleware.

Comment: Also, calling this store inside react AppWrapper.js component. 
import {} from './configureStore';

Comment: I think you're right it's circular dependency issue because
`redux-custom-middleware.js` is part of redux store and I am initializing redux store at app root component. while `./utils/api` have window.apiUrl  (i think) called after root component
Then how I can import this value. Any idea?

Comment: Move it somewhere higher in your dependency tree, breaking the circle. Otherwise, I _think_ if you wrap it in a simple function, e.g. `getApiUrl()`, that might also fix it.

Comment: I already tried
export const apiUrl = () =>  window.apiUrl || `${window.location.origin}/api`;
but it doesn't works.
let me try to put it somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: I meant `export function apiUrl() { return window.apiUrl; }`. IIRC JS handles exported functions differently from exported variables, even if both values are functions.

Comment: yes I used arrow function.

Comment: I know, I meant to literally use `export function`. You might know that functions are "predefined" in JS, e.g. `func(); function func(){}` will work, even though the function is defined after you actually call it. But `func(); const func = ()=>{};` would error. Therefore if the same happens for `export function`, that could possibly fix your problem. _Of course, breaking the circular dependency is still a better solution._

Comment: Thanks Kelvin now its working 
But here problem is there are about 60 files where we calling api.apiUrl
So, If I will change it then we need to test entire app again. I fear that will make problems.

Comment: Assuming all you do is replace `api.apiUrl` with `api.apiUrl()` or so, should be quite easy to test. Unless you mean for moving it to a different module, in which case I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Yes I agree with you it should be `api.apiUrl()` I will discuss with my team then I can change it.

For now I defined apiUrl constant directly inside `redux-custom-middleware.js` file. Later, I will may find solution. 

Really Thanks Kelvin for your time.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs you should add export function apiUrl() { return window.apiUrl; } 
as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a function instead of a constant, as functions are eagerly declared:

```js
export function apiUrl() {
    return window.apiUrl;
}
```

This makes it you can use `apiUrl()` immediately, since the circular dependency is fine since functions are "initialized" instantly.